# Get address of a WebAssembly exported function?

Tags: javascript, c, clang, webassembly

Assuming having this C code,

```
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
int mul(int a, int b) { return a * b; }
void *add_ptr() { return add; }
void *mul_ptr() { return mul; }
int op(int a, int b, int (*op) (int a, int b)) { return op(a, b); }
void *op_ptr() { return op; }
```

And compile it using a regular clang 8/9 to build a wasm file,

`clang --target=wasm32 a.c -nostdlib -Wl,--no-entry -Wl,--export=add -Wl,--export=mul -Wl,--export=mul_ptr -Wl,--export=add_ptr -Wl,--export=op -Wl,--export=op_ptr -o a.wasm`

And run it using a html page like,

```html
<script>
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('a.wasm')).then(result => alert(`
add: ${result.instance.exports.add(2, 3)}
mul: ${result.instance.exports.mul(2, 3)}

op_add: ${result.instance.exports.op(2, 3, result.instance.exports.add_ptr())}
op_mul: ${result.instance.exports.op(2, 3, result.instance.exports.mul_ptr())}

add_ptr: ${result.instance.exports.add_ptr()}
mul_ptr: ${result.instance.exports.mul_ptr()}
op_ptr: ${result.instance.exports.op_ptr()}

add.name: ${result.instance.exports.add.name}
mul.name: ${result.instance.exports.mul.name}
add_ptr.name: ${result.instance.exports.add_ptr.name}
mul_ptr.name: ${result.instance.exports.mul_ptr.name}
op.name: ${result.instance.exports.op.name}
`));
</script>
```

Which gives,

```
add: 5
mul: 6

op_add: 5
op_mul: 6

add_ptr: 1
mul_ptr: 2
op_ptr: 3

add.name: 0
mul.name: 1
add_ptr.name: 2
mul_ptr.name: 3
op.name: 4
```

What is the reliable way to get pointer address of `add`/`mul` in WebAssembly instance without having `{add|mul}_ptr` like functions? It can't be `.name` as `op.name` is different from `op_ptr` result.

The final intention here (I've reduced my usecase to this snippet) is to have `add` or `mul` address and pass it to `op` like function that gets a function pointer.

Comment: `int add_ptr() { return (int) add; }` is invalid. You can't convert a pointer to an `int`. It might work on a 32-bit system where both `int` and pointers are 32 bits wide (but it's still incorrect) but on a 64-bit system where `int` is *still* 32 bits but pointers are 64 bits, you will most likely get some really bad results.

Comment: Correct, fixed, thanks for the tip :) The intention here is to avoid having such function of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With WebAssembly functions, and the executable code they contain, live in a different namespace from data. As a result, you cannot obtain an address / pointer to a function and use that as an indirect mechanism for calling it.

What I think you are seeing in your code is the indices of the functions within the WebAssembly module's [function section](https://webassembly.org/docs/modules/#function-and-code-sections).

```
add_ptr: 1
mul_ptr: 2
op_ptr: 3
```

It is possible to perform dynamic function invocation via the underlying `call_indirect` WebAssembly operation. This allows you to call functions that are stored in the [table section](https://webassembly.org/docs/modules/#table-section).

However, I'm unsure whether the clang compiler supports a way to capitalise on this feature in order to support the behaviour you are looking for.